# How to count array of HTML element in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have arrays of radio buttons in my view

```
<input type="radio" id="s20" name="radio[1]" value="5" { { old('radio.1') ? checked="checked" : '' } } />
...
```

I need to get their count to pass it to a my PostRequestValidator via `<input type="hidden" value="count" name="count" />`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the number of inputs are not known *at priori*, but there are many ways to do it.

The easiest way is counting them using JavaScript or jQuery to update the *value* field of the hidden input.

```
$("input[type=hidden][name=count]").val(
      $("input[type=radio]").length
);
```

Obviously you can select those elements in better ways (using their name or class).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way using php? Just to complete the server side validation. I actually already solved this by counting it indirectly (using the adjacent input box). The problem was, I was using `foreach`, I found that `foreach` does not work, if no radio button is selected. So, my solution - use the `for loop` to count the radio buttons. I was just looking for other ways to count it, I mean directly counting the radio buttons.

Comment: Oh, I supposed that you didn't know the number of your input fields but, probably, I thought wrong. If you create those radio buttons inside your blade it's simple do it using *for* or *foreach*. I could edit my answer if you need other assistance.

Comment: It's supposed to be dynamically created, so yeah I do not know the number. Like I said, I found that `foreach` does not work, because if the user does not click/select any of the buttons nothing gets submitted to the validator in my case `PostsRequest`. YES, please edit your answer, I am curious how you do this. Thanks again